# How to to insert a footer (copyright and page number) IEEE Conference

Tags: numbering, ieeetran, footer, copyright

I am using two packages to deal with the footer: standard letter document class (`def`) and (`fancyhdr`).

I want that the copyright has to be only on the first page on the right side, and the page number is starting from 11 on the lift side. 
Now the result was that the copyright was  on the first page, but the number was starting from the second page. tried using fancy both were starting from the first page to the last page.

Is there a way to create that ?

```latex
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{fancyhdr,lipsum} % fancy package
\def\BibTeX{{\rm B\kern-.05em{\sc i\kern-.025em b}\kern-.08em
T\kern-.1667em\lower.7ex\hbox{E}\kern-.125emX}}
{\lstset{basicstyle=\scriptsize,xleftmargin=.04\textwidth,#1}}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%FooterLift
\makeatletter
\def\ps@IEEEtitlepagestyle{ % Standard Letter Document Class package 
    \def\@oddfoot{\mycopyrightnotice}
}
\def\mycopyrightnotice{
    {\footnotesize xxxxx~\copyright2019 IEEE\hfill}
}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%FooterRight
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead{} % clear all header fields
\fancyfoot{} % clear all footer fields
\setcounter{page}{11}
\fancyfoot[RO,LE]{\thepage}
\fancyfoot[LO,CE]{xxxxx~\copyright2019 IEEE}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}

% \thispagestyle{firstPage}% 
\begin{document}
\begin{abstract}
LaTeX is a high-quality typesetting system
\end{abstract}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Class option [conference] turns off all headers and footers.

Comment: Dr.Amod did you find the solution to this problem, I am also facing this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you are setting up a conference template.  Otherwise, don't do this.

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{fancyhdr,lipsum} % fancy package
%\def\BibTeX{{\rm B\kern-.05em{\sc i\kern-.025em b}\kern-.08em
%T\kern-.1667em\lower.7ex\hbox{E}\kern-.125emX}}
%{\lstset{basicstyle=\scriptsize,xleftmargin=.04\textwidth,#1}}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%FooterLift
\makeatletter
\def\ps@headings{% default to standard twoside headers, no footers
% will change later if the mode requires otherwise
\let\@oddhead\@empty
\let\@evenhead\@empty
\def\@oddfoot{\@IEEEheaderstyle\hfil\thepage}%
\def\@evenfoot{\@IEEEheaderstyle\thepage\hfil\hbox{}}% not used, oneside
}
\def\ps@IEEEtitlepagestyle{% default title page headers, no footers
\let\@oddhead\@empty
\let\@evenhead\@empty
\def\@oddfoot{\footnotesize xxxxx~\copyright2019 IEEE\hfill\thepage}%
\let\@evenfoot\@empty
}
\makeatother
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%FooterRight

\pagestyle{headings}
\setcounter{page}{11}
\thispagestyle{IEEEtitlepagestyle}
\begin{document}

\begin{abstract}
LaTeX is a high-quality typesetting system
\end{abstract}

\lipsum[1-30]
\end{document}
```

Comment: I tried that it shows me the page number on the right of the header, how can the page number be on the right of the footer.

Comment: Sorry, IEEE normally puts the page number in the headers.

Comment: Yes I agree but the conference wants it on the footer which is annoying!

Answer (score -1):

From this video, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GDX2Y7jxuAA

copy the text given below and paste above `\begin{document}` in your `.tex` file

```
%%%%%for header%%%%%

\makeatletter
 \let\old@ps@headings\ps@headings
 \let\old@ps@IEEEtitlepagestyle\ps@IEEEtitlepagestyle
 \def\confheader#1{%
 % for all pages except the first
 \def\ps@headings{%
 \old@ps@headings%
 \def\@oddhead{\strut\hfill#1\hfill\strut}%
 \def\@evenhead{\strut\hfill#1\hfill\strut}%
 }%
 % for the first page
 \def\ps@IEEEtitlepagestyle{%
 \old@ps@IEEEtitlepagestyle%
 \def\@oddhead{\strut\hfill#1\hfill\strut}%
 \def\@evenhead{\strut\hfill#1\hfill\strut}%
 }%
 \ps@headings%
 }
 \makeatother

\confheader{%
 2017 Conference on Information and Communication Technology (CICT'17)
 }


%%%%%%%for footer%%%%%%%%%%%

 \usepackage[pscoord]{eso-pic}
\newcommand{\placetextbox}[3]{
 \setbox0=\hbox{#3}
 \AddToShipoutPictureFG*{ \put(\LenToUnit{#1\paperwidth},\LenToUnit{#2\paperheight}){\vtop{{\null}\makebox[0pt][c]{#3}}}
 }
 }
 \placetextbox{.23}{0.055}{\small{978-1-5386-1866-0/17/\$31.00~\copyright 2017 IEEE}}
```